# Remove csrf token only for single method - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, csrf-protection

I am using paytabs payment gateway api. In that api, a redirect url have to given, so that once the transaction is completed, the page will redirect automatically to your given redirect url. The url was a GET url but since the response of the api comes as a POST type, I was unable to use get url. To resolve that issue, I made that route a POST url but by making it post method, I am not getting any CSRF token. In the end, I get this issue.

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:
```

Is there any way by which I could disbale CSRF token functionality for only single POST url?

*--SUGGESTION TRIED--*
I did this as per your suggestion

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    protected $except = [
        'signup/complete',
    ];
}
```

and now getting

```
Class 'Middleware' not found
```

Comment: which version of laravel 5 do you use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris):

> Typically, you should place these kinds of routes outside of the web middleware group that the RouteServiceProvider applies to all routes in the  `routes/web.php` file. However, you may also exclude the routes by adding their URIs to the $except property of the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    protected $except = [
        'stripe/*',
        'http://example.com/foo/bar',
        'http://example.com/foo/*',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your help @alexey but it gives another error and stopped my every routes.

Comment: @nerdyDev edit existing middleware and not create a new one.

Comment: i have updated the question, under the question i have done the changes in web.php as your said and the response in question as well. thanks

Comment: This url is not under middleware, its just seperate. I provided       ////<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">//// in forms to handle this token, not by routes.

Comment: @nerdyDev I'm talking about the `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` middleware.

Comment: Declaration of App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::handle($request, App\Http\Middleware\Closure $next) should be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::handle($request, Closure $next)  -------------------------------------This error comes by that changes in verifycsrftoken.php

Comment: @nerdyDev you're getting both errors because you're changing the middleware. Don't change anything, just add your route to the `$except` array.

Comment: @nerdyDev no. Look at the original `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware. There is the `$except` property with an empty array. Copy the path you want to exclude in this array and save.

Comment: That worked @alexey thanks alot. U deserve a up vote. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

You can exception in csrf middleware. go to app/http/Middleware/VirefyCsrfToken.php

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier{
    protected $except = [
     'route url1',
     'route url2',

    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for how use localhost
in your project folder /app/http/middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php edit

```
protected $except = [
    //
    'http://localhost/blog/return_url',  // your url
];
```