# Laravel: How do I use other data than email and password?

Tags: laravel, authentication

I want to use only CPF number to let the login. CPF is like a Social Secure Number or else alike, and that´s a unique number in Brazil.
I already have a data table with this number, so no registration needed.

Where do I change the code to accept CPF instead email and password, please?

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't need a password?? Can log into anyones account?

Comment: Well, the user doesn´t have a password at this moment yet. But there is another two data that I can use, like "group" and "quota".
Anyways, those fields do not default to Laravel.

So, I will have to use not the default fields.

Comment: Updated my answer, tested it locally and works. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to override these methods in your LoginController, just paste this in and change accordingly.

Change default `email` to `cpf` field name:

```php
public function username()
{
    return 'cpf'; // or whatever field you use to login
}
```

Do validation here with credentials:

```php
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        $this->username() => 'required|string|exists:users,cpf',
    ]);
}
```

Do the login request. Here we look for user then log him in manually and redirect you to the dashboard (home), if it fails, you will be redirected back with the input that was inserted into the form:

```php
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    $user = User::where('cpf', $request->cpf)->first();

    if ($user) {
        Auth::login($user);
        return redirect()->intended('home');
    }

    return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->all());
}
```

**DB table I tested with:**

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('cpf')->unique();
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: open file `AuthenticatesUsers.php`

Step 2: update the `username()` function, default you will see email. you need to update it to cpf.

```
   public function username()
    {
        return 'cpf';
    }
```

Step 3: update the `credentials(Request $request)` function, by default it is password. you can change as per your approach. if you do not want it,you can remove field for password too!

```
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        //return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
        return $request->only($this->username());
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It returns a 419 error
"Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again."

Comment: This may be another issue. you can read answers of [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583886/post-request-in-laravel-5-7-error-419-sorry-your-session-has-expired)

Comment: Probably. I have installed "backpack" before trying to do it. I think will rm -R and restart but now, coding the front-login first

Comment: YES! That´s the problem. Reinstall all from stretch and works like a breeze!