# Session not storing data in Vue.js & Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.7

I am trying to store data into the Laravel session on each AJAX call from the vue.js.

I want to add a product in Laravel cart using session but it's not storing any kind of session data. I have also added web middleware but no luck.

**api.php**

```
<?php
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api'],function(){
        Route::resource('product','ProductController');
        Route::post('add-to-cart','ProductController@addToCart');
    });
```

**ProductController.php**

```
<?php
    public function addToCart(Request $request){
    $product = $request->all();

    $cart = Session::get('cart');
    $cart[$product['id']] = $product;
    Session::push('cart', $cart);

    return Response::json(['success' => true, 'cart_items' => Session::get('cart')]);
}
```

**ProductListComponene.vue**

```
addToCartProduct(product){
    fetch('api/add-to-cart',{
        method: 'post',
        body:JSON.stringify(product),
        headers:{
            'content-type':'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of your routes are registered in `api` middleware and if you check the `app/Http/Kernel.php` file, you will see the it doesn't have `StartSession` middelware registered. So you have to start the session first in order to save data to the session.

[image]

Comment: Added this  `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` into the middleware and working fine now. Thanks.

Comment: also good to take a look on this answer of mine, related to the session drivers https://stackoverflow.com/a/53253184/2693543

Comment: this dismantled error messages on every other blade for me. very annoying.