# Form post request return error 419 unknown status laravel

Tags: php, laravel, post, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to create new user with id_ward, but when I post submit form it returns error 419(unknown status)

please help me

```
<div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Thêm user</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="./admin/users/add_user" method="post" id="form-add-user">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token() }}" />
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label for="add_user_area">Phường/xã:</label>
                        <select id="add_user_area" class="form-control" name="id_ward">
                            @foreach ($areas as $area)
                                <option value={{$area->id}}>{{$area->name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('form-add-user').submit()"
                class="btn btn-primary">Thêm
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Đóng</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

And this is my controller

```
function postAddUser(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User;
    $user->id_ward = $request->id_ward;
    $user->save();
    return redirect('admin/users/list_user');
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post request in Laravel 5.7, laravel 5.8 --- Error - 419 Sorry, your session has expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583886/post-request-in-laravel-5-7-laravel-5-8-error-419-sorry-your-session-has)

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect your form using devtools does your token has any value at all? or does it have an empty value?

Try adding this line `request()->session()->regenerateToken();` to your controller before you show view containing the form:

```
public function showAddUserForm()
{
    request()->session()->regenerateToken();
    return view('user.create');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token() }}" />
```

->

```
@csrf
```

It will help https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf

If that doesn't help
Let's understand. 
What we have written in routes? There must be something like.

```
Route::post('/users/add_user', 'UsersController@postAddUser')->name('postAddUser');
```

in controller

```
public function postAddUser() { 
    $user = new User(); 
    $user->id_ward = request()->id_ward; 
    $user->save(); 
    return redirect('admin/users/list_user'); 
}
```

in view

```
<form action="{{ route("postAddUser") }}" method="post" id="form-add-user">
```

Comment: nope it's not working
I'm using this 
<form>
@csrf
</form>

Comment: Let's look for another solution, added more details to the answer.

Comment: what " ->name('postAddUser'); " using for. Can you explain it ?

Comment: This is an alias for the route. It is convenient to use it in the template in this way `<form action="{{ route("postAddUser") }}"`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue because I was trying to add a modal with a form to a page that already has a form. To solve it I gave my forms unique ids and then with the help of the form attribute added the form id to all my inputs including the csrf input. Below is an example. I am hopeful it would solve your problem

```
<form action="{{route('template.update')}}" id="edit_template_{{$template->id}}" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token() }}" form="edit_template_{{$template->id}}">
<input type="number" name = "unit_price" form="edit_template_{{$template->id}}">
 <button  form="edit_template_{{$template->id}}">Save</button>
</form>
```