# Laravel 6 Showed 419 | page expired

Tags: php, laravel

In a local server the following laravel project working fine, But When the project upload on online server it's showing the problem.

When trying to login then its show:

> 419 | page expired.

I have cleared route, view, cache, and config when I uploaded it on online serve.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Post request in Laravel - Error - 419 Sorry, your session/ 419 your page has expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583886/post-request-in-laravel-error-419-sorry-your-session-419-your-page-has-exp)

Answer (score 2):

Your error seems to be related to 'csrf_token'. Either it is missing the csrf token or your route needs to be put in the exclusion list. See [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris) for help.

Answer (score 2):

Just put `{{ csrf_field() }}` like others have said above, below login form, Laravel does not allow request forgery attacks.

Comment: im using pwa how to add csrf_field, I am using sanctum

Answer (score 1):

We get this error page when CSRF token get expired. This issue generally happens when you load a page with form(eg. login page, registration page) then after a long time you submit the form. We get this because, the CSRF is expired by the time.

**To solve this:**

You can increase the lifetime in the `config/session.php` file.

Comment: Sir, I have increased lifetime of session but it still not working

Answer (score 1):

There's also the `SESSION_LIFETIME` key in your `.env` file.

It refers to the number of minutes to hold the session active, in minutes.

I had issues with mine set to 1 minute for testing, and then I forgot about it, so my CSRF would expire quickly while filling out forms.

I set it to 60 minutes to fix:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=60
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using the database driver for your sessions and either UUIDs or ULIDs for your user IDs, make sure the `user_id` field in the `sessions` table reflects the correct format. If it's a `bigint unsigned` field, it'll cause 419 errors if you're using ULIDs or UUIDs.