# Laravel: form submit return 419 and csrf already set on the form

Tags: laravel

Hello I have a login form that returns a 419-page expired error every time I submit it I already set the `@csrf` inside the form but nothing and also tried the `csrf_filed` inside the form and also but it in the header inside of meta tag but still not working, am working on a live server so I downloaded the files on my `localhost` and tried to submit the form again and everything worked fine on my `localhost` but on the server it still returns the error `419 pages expired`, and also tried to submit the request to a function that just returns hello world but it also returns page expired i have nothing on my head I tried everything I know and nothing worked please I need help with this.

And thanks a lot

Comment: Try clearing your cache `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Post request in Laravel - Error - 419 Sorry, your session has expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583886/post-request-in-laravel-error-419-sorry-your-session-has-expired)

Comment: no, I tried everything on that the session stored on a file and checked the storage access everything is fine as I said above the code is running on localhost fine but the problem on the version on the live server

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `cache` cause this problem. Try below commands.

These will clear all cache and generate new token for your project.

```
php artisan key:generate
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: didn't work I made a route that clears everything you wrote above but nothing happened the problem still exists.