# Laravel 8 shows 419 PAGE EXPIRED while login/signup

Tags: localhost, cpanel, laravel-8, migrate, php-7.4

I'm using eClass - Learning Management System by media-city, which built in Laravel 8 (PHP 7.4). Bought it from themeforest. It's currently works fine run on server. But recent time I bought a new domain. So that, I want to switch old domain to new one. I tried to run my system on localhost & new domain; it's frontend works fine. But when I tried to login or signup; it shows "419 PAGE EXPIRED."

I tried ->

php artisan key:generate
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear

There is @csrf in login/signup page. Nothing is working; so, need a solution.

Comment: Please review this question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583886/post-request-in-laravel-error-419-sorry-your-session-419-your-page-has-exp)

Comment: None of these above worked for me. In https://; it works fine but in http://; It's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Jetstream application that was displaying the same error in production environment.

I solved it by adding the following code to the boot() function of AppServiceProvider:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

...

if($this->app->environment('production') || $this->app->environment('staging')) {
    URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

Please let us know if this solution fits your problem or if you have found another one.

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/nova/frustrating-419-page-expired-on-login-using-jetstream