# Registration form doesn't work on the server (laravel+react)

Tags: reactjs, laravel, forms, deployment, csrf

I'm trying to use laravel with react and locally everything works fine, but when I send it to the server and try to register a user, it's returning 419 - page expired.
[page expired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqQxK.png)

- I searched and saw that it could be missing the CSRF token, but I tried to add it as a field in the form and it didn't change anything.
- Because it's working locally I believe it may be a configuration that is missing from the server, I'm using Heroku.
- Note: I only did the download about laravel with react login and push it to heroku, my only change was in AppServiceProvider.php to work with HTTPS protocol.
  [AppServiceProvider changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lNZD.png)

Comment: since you said your only change is in AppSer..Provider: you should also make sure the session domain is set correctly. Good reference answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54561833/3532758 and other answers there.

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot, I think the session domain was wrong, now it's working.