# sharedwithexpose.com - laravel redirects to local host

Tags: laravel, routes

I am using sharedwithexpose.com.  It seems to work well.  localhost/login goes to my login page, as does subdomain.us-1.sharedwithexpose.com/login.  however, when I actually login, using subdomain.us-1.sharedwithexpose.com/login  the computer returns "419 Page Expired" and the url is changed to localhost/login.

will changing the value of the APP_ENV variable prevent the web.php routes file from changing the url back to localhost from subdomain.us-1.sharedwithexpose.com?

My routes are defined in web.php like

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->get('/home', function () {
    return view('home');
})->name('home');
```

That is the landing page after you login.  My APP_ENV=local.

thanks.

rbd

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all, you may try with browser refresh (`Ctrl/cmd + Shift + r`).
2. Then check you have included `@crsf` in login form. like [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583886/post-request-in-laravel-error-419-sorry-your-session-419-your-page-has-exp)
3. and then check in `.env` file you have `APP_URL="http://subdomain.us-1.sharedwithexpose.com"` or `APP_URL="https://subdomain.us-1.sharedwithexpose.com"`

Comment: Hi.  thank you.  I do have @crsf in the login form.  Rendered as:
```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="xxx_tokenvalue_xxx">
```
I have refreshed
I added the APP_URL value as suggested.
performed an Artisan Cache:Clear

I am using Fortify Package

the site continues to render the links with "localhost" in stead of the value in the APP_URL variable in .env.

Any Thoughts?

Comment: you may try `php artisan optimize:clear` in case of any cache related issue

Comment: or please check with `dd($request->all()` and make sure it has `_token` before doing actual login stuff

Comment: I think the issue comes before all that.    I believe the problem lay with the laravel named routes.  if I change <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}"> to <form method="POST" action = "/login">  The login is successful.  however when i use the named routes to produce appropriate links, the root domain gets changed to "localhost".  Not sure why yet.