# get data by user Entered laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I tried to let the user enter his ID to display the payment recode
I have two model
Customer, payment which has one to many relations
here is my form

```
  <form action= "{{url('/Check')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/from-data">
    @csrf    
    <div class="row gtr-uniform">
            <h3>Please Enter youe National ID</h3>
            <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
                <input type="text" name="cust_id" id="cust_id" value="" placeholder="ID" required/>
            </div>
            
            <!-- Break -->
            <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall">
                <ul class="actions">
                    <li><input type="submit" id="btnclaim" value="Search" class="primary" /></li>
                    <li><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

this is the route statement

```
Route::post('/Check',[paymetController::class,'Check']);
```

and here is the controller

```
public function Check(Request $request){
    $cust_id=$request->CustomerID;
    $pay=Customer::with('payment')->find($cust_id);
    return view('DisplayPay',compact('pay'));
}
```

when I submit the form I got

```
 419 PAGE EXPIRED
```

Comment: This error normally occurs due to expired or absence of `csrf` token. But you already have `@csrf` directive. So try to refresh the page and submit the form again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Post request in Laravel - Error - 419 Sorry, your session/ 419 your page has expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583886/post-request-in-laravel-error-419-sorry-your-session-419-your-page-has-exp)

Answer (score -1):

run the following command:

1. `php artisan optimize`
2. `php artisan optimize:clear`
3. `php artisan serve`
4. `npm run dev`