# CSRF token mismatch error on any form submission in Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2, csrf

I have recently deployed a Laravel application on AWS EC2 and configured it to be served through the Nginx web server. The website functions flawlessly when accessed locally. However, when accessing it on the live server, I encounter an issue when attempting to submit any form, such as login, registration, or password recovery. The error message received is `419 (unknown status)` with the accompanying description stating a "CSRF token mismatch."

Despite researching various solutions through online resources, the commonly suggested remedy of sending the CSRF token in the `Ajax request header` did not resolve the issue. This CSRF token had already been correctly implemented from the project's inception.

ajaxSetup code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}});
```

Also from what I understand the csrf token is being sent to the server too
[image]

This is how the request header looks in `LOCALHOST`
[image]

Comment: It can depend on the configuration of your session driver, take a look here firstly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583886/post-request-in-laravel-error-419-sorry-your-session-419-your-page-has-exp