# 419 error when authenticating to a Laravel website with JMeter

Tags: laravel, jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing, load-testing

I am currently facing an issue with authentication on a Laravel website using JMeter. I have set up a load test with JMeter to simulate multiple users logging into the site, but I encounter a 419 error during the authentication process.

I have followed several tutorials and guides to configure my test plan in JMeter, but I am unable to identify the exact cause of the error. I expected the authentication test to work correctly, but I receive this error message indicating that authentication has failed.

Initially, I used a "Regular Expression Extractor" on the GET request to retrieve the XSRF-TOKEN and then associate it with the header of the POST request, but this does not seem to work. I have included screenshots of my test plan in JMeter, as well as relevant code snippets from my test script and the errors I encounter.

I am open to any suggestions or advice on how to resolve this issue. If anyone has encountered this type of error during authentication on a Laravel site with JMeter, I would be grateful for any assistance you can provide.

I normally speak French, but I have translated, so please forgive me if it seems inconsistent. Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: 419 is from a CSRF token mismatch, so you can continue to work on resolving that part

Comment: @lagbox Thank you for taking the time to respond to my message If you can give me more details that would help me a lot. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Post request in Laravel - Error - 419 Sorry, your session/ 419 your page has expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583886/post-request-in-laravel-error-419-sorry-your-session-419-your-page-has-exp)

The error you're getting is due to missing or improperly correlated [CSRF token](https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf), you need to extract it from the previous response body (or [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)) and provide it instead of recorded (hard-coded) value in the next request.

The process is known as [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) and there is a lot of information on it in the web. You can also check out [What is CSRF & How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Websites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-csrf-load-testing) article which is a little bit more specific for your problem.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond to my message. I have taken the time to visit each link you provided in your message, but I found a difference with my specific case. In other cases, the CSRF token is found in a hidden input field with an attribute, but in my case, I go to the link https:xxxxx/api/sanctum/csrf-cookie, and the token is found in the cookies of the link. I should associate these cookies with the authentication link: https:xxxxxapi/auth/login with the parameters.

Comment: I retrieved the token using a "Regular Expression Extractor" and then associated it in the header of the authentication link (I included the screenshots, but unfortunately, they were deleted).

Comment: If the CSRF token comes as a cookie you can get it directly from [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager). Add the next line to *user.properties* file: `CookieManager.save.cookies=true` and restart JMeter. Once done you will be able to refer cookies value in form of `${COOKIE_YOUR_COOKIE_NAME_HERE}`. More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-cookie-manager). You might also need to [URL-encode](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) the token or vice versa.

Comment: Thank you once again for your response, I am truly grateful. I followed the instructions you mentioned exactly. It seems that with the HTTP Cookie Manager, cookies are automatically associated with each URL. In the responses, I can see the cookies, but this time the error has become 422. Unfortunately, I am unable to provide screenshots. If you don't mind, I can provide my contact information so that I can send you the screenshots. Thank you very much.

Comment: I finally managed to solve the problem. Thank you for your time, it helped me immensely. For your information, here are the steps I took to resolve the issue:

1. Modify `CookieManager.save.cookies=true` in the `jmeter.properties` file. By default, it's set to false.
2. Use Regular Expression Extractor on the GET request to retrieve the XSRF_TOKEN token.
3. Implement a BeanShell script to decode the retrieved token (Also on the GET request).
4. Add the decoded token to the header of the POST request.

Please ensure that your data is sent in JSON format or other appropriate formats.